# PostgreSQL 11 Select previous value in row to compare with out sub select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say you have a table in PostgreSQL 11 with sets of values something like this below.

```
12 18
11 12
5  12
9  18
7  19
14 18
11 16
6  12
4  11
5  9
```

Is their a way to do a select with out using sub selects or select by using functions or trigger/functions to find where each value is lower than previous or could be higher than previous but this example is lower than previous (could be 2 row or 15+ rows) in both column and first column went higher than last row to terminate the select making the condition positive?

I do not know of a way to have present variables inside of a select.  If I could keep a look back variable then I should be able to do this.  I am wondering if anyone out their has ever come across this and made it work inside a select or they went outside of the database into GoLang / Python / C++ / Perl / PHP / etc.  Very simple to do once I leave the database but I would really like to keep this inside PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: there is no such thing as the "previous" row unless you can provide a column for an `order by`. I don't see such a column. But in general access to the "previous" row is done using the `lag()` function

Comment: Please add your expected output and your order criterion